# Correct folder permissions for Symfony on Linux?

Tags: ubuntu, symfony1, file-permissions

I have moved my XP installation of Symfony (1.3.2) to Linux (Ubuntu 9.10). I now get a blank screen. Upon checking the Apache log files, I realised that apache daemon did not have permissions to create the cache folder.

I used chgrp and chown to manually assign permission. When I then accessed the homepage, I got a 403 forbidden message, saying that permission not allowed to access .htaccess file.

What exactly are the required folder/file permissions for Symfony on Linux?

The documentation fails to mention this anywhere

Answer (score 11):

### symfony permissions

symfony's CLI tool offers a task to fix part of this problem:

for **sf1.0.x**, use: `symfony fix-perms` from the command line in the root directory of your project on the Linux server.

for **sf1.1+**, use: `symfony project:permissions` from the same location.

---

You may also want to address overall permissions for Apache on the server:

### Apache/system permissions

I use these two commands as part of an overall permission fix on hosts with permissions:

```
chown -R username:group /path/to/project_dir
chmod -R 775 /path/to/project_dir
```

`username` and `group` here are the owners of the parent dir, generally.

You can combine these and the symfony CLI commands into a short batch script if you like, and add this to the root of your project dir.

Answer (score 1):

I have .htaccess set to 775 and cache folder 777 if that helps?, which user/group owns the files depends on how you've configured your server.